# How do I insert word from text and keep track of word frequency by bst?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

My homework is given a dict structure that contains a tree to store word. In main.c I'm creating a dictionary called stopwords that read in word from a file and insert word into the dict. In dict.c, I need to implement a data structure that can update and show the dictionary from main.

*Q1. Will my insert function work in updating stopword in main.c?*
*Q2. How should I print every word and frequency in the dictionary? It seems I can't use recursive as passing in Dict type. Thanks*

**dict.c**

```
typedef struct _DictNode *Link;
typedef struct _DictNode *Tree;
typedef struct _DictRep *Dict;

typedef struct _WFreq {
   char  *word;  
   int    freq;  
} WFreq;

typedef struct  _DictNode {
   WFreq  data;
   Link   left;
   Link   right;
   //int   height;
} DictNode;

struct _DictRep { //pointer to the root node 
   Link tree;
};

// create new empty Dictionary
Dict newDict() 
{
   Dict new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
   //if (new == NULL) err (EX_OSERR, "couldn't allocate Dict");
   new->tree = NULL;
   return new;
}

// insert new word into Dictionary
// return 0 when word is found already and 1 when not found
//WFreq *DictInsert(Dict d, char *w)
int DictInsert(Dict d, char *w)
{
   int direction;
   Link temp = malloc(sizeof(DictNode));
   temp->left = NULL;
   temp->right = NULL;
   temp->data.word = w;
   temp->data.freq = 1;

   if (d->tree == NULL){
      d->tree = temp;
   } else {
      Link prev = NULL;
      Link this = d->tree;
      
      //find the node that should point to this node
      while (this != NULL){
         prev = this;
         if((direction = strcmp(this->data.word, temp->data.word)) == 0){
            //word already exists 
            this->data.freq++;
            free(temp);
            return 0;
         } else {
            if (direction < 0)
               this = this->right;
            else 
               this = this->left;
         }
      }
      //update the prev node 
      if (direction < 0)
         prev->right = temp;
      else
         prev->left = temp;
   }
   return 1;
}

// print a dictionary
void showDict(Dict d)
{
   //recursive?
   printf("%s %d\n",d->tree->data.word, d->tree->data.freq);
   return;
}
```

**main.c**

```
FILE *in = fopen("stopwords", "r");
   Dict stopwords = newDict();
   char *stop_word = malloc(MAXWORD);
   while(fscanf(in, "%s", stop_word)!=EOF){
      //reading in characters 
      DictInsert(stopwords, stop_word);
   }
   showDict(stopwords);
   fclose(in);
   free(stop_word);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q1. Will my insert function work in updating stopword in main.c?

The `w` parameter in `DictInsert()` points to a buffer allocated to `stop_word` in "main.c", but that buffer is reused for each word in the "stopwords" file.  Therefore, `DictInsert()` needs to copy word to a new buffer.

If the non-standard `strdup()` function is available, you can use that:

```
temp->data.word = strdup(w);
```

If `strdup()` is not available, you can do this instead:

```
temp->data.word = malloc(strlen(w) + 1);
strcpy(temp->data.word, w);
```

If a duplicate word is found, free `temp->data.word` before freeing `temp`:

```
free(temp->data.word);
free(temp);
```

> Q2. How should I print every word and frequency in the dictionary? It seems I can't use recursive as passing in Dict type.

You can define a function that prints a `Link` recursively:

```
void showDictHelper(Link tree)
{
    if (tree == NULL)
        return;
    showDictHelper(tree->left);
    printf("%s %d\n",tree->data.word, tree->data.freq);
    showDictHelper(tree->right);
}
```

Then call it from `showDict()`:

```
void showDict(Dict d)
{
    showDictHelper(d->tree);
}
```